Disable side channel mitigations for all virtual machines
After enabling WSL-2 under Windows 10 VMWare Workstation (Version 17.0.2 build-21581411) runs all virtual machines with side channel mitigations enabled.
Even after disabling the features Hyper-V and WSL and restarting the system.
The VMWare article VMs with side channel mitigations enabled may exhibit performance degradation shows how to disable side channel mitigations for a single virtual machine.
But this disables side channel mitigations only for the current virtual machine (actually only for the current snapshot).
Is there a way to default disable side channel mitigations?
Which information does VMWare gets after enabling WSL-2 that it enables side channel mitigations?

You can disable virtualization based security through a group policy if you want

For VMware Workstation or VMware Player:
Locate the configuration file:
For Windows, the file is usually located at C:\ProgramData\VMware\VMware Workstation\config.ini.
For Linux, the file is located at /etc/vmware/config.
Edit the configuration file:
Open the configuration file in a text editor with administrative privileges.
Add the line:
ulm.disableMitigations="TRUE"
to the end of the configuration file:
Save and close the file.
